# Manipulating TextEditingControllers from another class

Tags: flutter

In my `class1` i have defined the following:

```
  TextEditingController myTextCtrl1 = new TextEditingController();

  Widget getStatus(Map<String, String> StatusCode, var num) {
      return Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 50,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: myTextCtrl1,
              onChanged: (val) {
                num = val;
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
```

This method is going to be called in `class2` which is a Stateful Widget. i would like to assign the controller some text in the `initState()` method. I have written the following code:

```
Map<String, String> _maps;

@override
  void initState() {
    Map<String, String> maps = {"404": "resource not found"};
    setState(() {
      _maps = maps;
      Class1().myTextCtrl1.text = "${_maps["404"]}";
    });

    super.initState();
  }
```

then in the `build` method:

```
...

Class1().getStatus(_maps ,var num),

...
```

However, the `TextFormField` remains empty. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you are creating a new instance of the `Class1` class each time, by doing `Class1()...`. Instead, you should keep a reference to the instance, which can then be passed to the other class that you want to make your manipulations from.

For example:

```dart
// This is a global variable.
final _instance = Class1();

class Message extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _instance.controller.text = 'Some text here';

    return TextFormField(
      controller: _instance.controller,
      ...
    );
  }
}

class MessageButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
      ...
      onPressed: () {
        _instance.controller.text = 'New text!';
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is NOT the best way to do it. A better approach would be to use something like [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod), which - while it makes use of global variables - has proper garbage collection and makes state management more structured.